# How do I access this JSON data in angular template?

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm a bit lost. My JSON data is stored in

```
$scope.cuisines = data;
```

if I console.log(data), the result is

```
"[{\"pk\": 1, \"model\": \"swings.cuisine\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Chinese\"}},
{\"pk\": 2, \"model\": \"swings.cuisine\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Indian\"}}, 
{\"pk\": 3, \"model\": \"swings.cuisine\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Japanese\"}}]"
```

If I try to do

```
<li ng-repeat='cuisine in cuisines'>{{cuisine.fields.name}}</li>
```

I get

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: place in places, Duplicate key: string:"
```

I tried adding "track by cuisine.pk" (along with other variations) as suggested in some of the stackoverflow answers to this question. I keep getting the same error though. If I add track by $index, I just get an unlimited list of bullet points with no info.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: where is `data` coming from? Seems like it's a string and it shouldn't be. It should have been JSON parsed to javascript array already

Comment: I think you might have the wrong place for the bug. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/V4s6D/) with your code and it works fine. Are you missing something?

Comment: hmm, thats weird, my code is coming from django, its serialized and passed to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `data` you get is in string format parse it before setting it into the angular template

**JS**

```
var data = "[{\"pk\": 1, \"model\": \"swings.cuisine\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Chinese\"}}, {\"pk\": 2, \"model\": \"swings.cuisine\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Indian\"}},{\"pk\": 3, \"model\": \"swings.cuisine\", \"fields\": {\"name\": \"Japanese\"}}]";

function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.cuisines = JSON.parse(data);

}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4s6D/2/)

Comment: This is very very weird, JSON.parse doesn't work. I dont understand whats happening. If I define my data as you do, not part of a callback, my list displays fine. If I use my call back data (which is the exact same), I keep get the ng-repeat error.

Comment: @user3739703: Then try without JSON.parse. Also just check the `typeof data`

Comment: I have no idea whats happening that making it work but it turns out I need to double parse information retrieved from my server to make it work. I have no idea why, single phrase only works if I define my data manually. I have no idea why this is happening because the starting data before being phrased is the exact same for both. But none the less I guess problem solved. Thanks

EDIT: Apparently my initial data passed from the server is a string, phrasing it the first time leaves it as a string and the second time turns it into an object allowing it to work. Very weird